# Fluid height dependent on content in Drupal theme

Tags: html, css, drupal

How is it possible to have a fluid div change it's height according to the content in css alone, or do I have to do it in PHP?

The reason why is because I am making a theme for Drupal and the content will change for each page of the theme.

For example, the middle content div doesn't have a set height, but depending on the article or page length specified in the Drupal back end, the content div will change accordingly.

Amar

Comment: Mabe <div style="clear:both"></div> after the content div will help you?

Comment: What height would I set in the first place for the content div?

Comment: Isn't it stratched by content?

Comment: If you have a fluid content div in non fluid div, then you must add clear both div after the fluid div, so non fluid div have same height as inner fluid div.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ look Greate collapse section

Comment: Thanks it worked great. I'd give you the tick but you answered as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fluid content div in non fluid div, then you must add clear both div after the fluid div, so non fluid div have same height as inner fluid div

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```